# Image attribute not saving in test with FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin, factory-bot, rspec-rails

### App

I have a column `bg_image` in a table `User` that uses a carrierwave uploader

```
mount_uploader :bg_image, UserLogoUploader
```

It gets set in an activeadmin/formtastic form like below:

```
f.input :bg_image, :label => "Background Image", :as => :file
```

### Tests (where the problem is)

I have a factory for `User` to make the basic version with all the required fields (which works in other tests), but then when i try to add `bg_image` it doesn't get saved.

factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    stuff "set in factory"
  end
end
```

test file:

```
let!(:user) { create(:user, :something => "that works", :bg_image => "doesntWork.png") }

it "inspects the element" do
  puts user.inspect
end
```

prints out

```
#<User id: 1, stuff: "set in factory", something: "that works", bg_image: nil>
```

I just can't seem to figure out why it doesn't save!

I tried a few things like setting it to `File` object but that won't work because it needs to be a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im pretty sure its not working because in your tests you are using the bg_image as a string, remember you mounted an uploader to bg_image and you need to use it for carrierwave to work, i would check carrierwave documentation for info about testing, hope it helps !

here is some documentation:

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#testing-with-carrierwave

Comment: That link is more testing the uploading, i want to test the attribute being used after the uploading

Answer (score 1):

My factory image file:

```
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :image do
    file { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'spec','support', 'test_images', 'audi.png')) }
    created Time.now.to_s
    tags    { Faker::Lorem.characters 20 }
    user    { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  end
end
```